# Push notification is not receiving very first time

Tags: ios, node.js, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am sending push notification from the node server to iPhone and Android. It was successfully sent to the APNS/GCM and successfully receiving the notifications to the mobile devices. But, in iPhone 6, push notification is not receiving very first time after that it's receiving notification. It's happening in following stage:

1. Installing application and opening first time.
2. If application no longer in use.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple says in [Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html) and [Troubleshooting Push Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG23)

> Delivery of notifications is a “best effort”, not guaranteed. It is
>   not intended to deliver data to your app, only to notify the user that
>   there is new data available.

**Updated:**

The problem is that Apple closes the connection when it cannot process a message. So, updated the code in Node push notification server.js as below and it's working perfectly:

```
var connectCallback = function (err) {
  // gracefully handle auth problems
  if (err && err.name === 'GatewayAuthorizationError') {
    console.log('Authentication Error: %s', err.message);
    process.exit(1);
  }

  // handle any other err (not likely)
  else if (err) {
    throw err;
  }

  // it worked!
  var env = agent.enabled('sandbox')
    ? 'sandbox'
    : 'production';

  console.log('apnagent [%s] gateway connected', env);
};

agent.connect(connectCallback);

setInterval(function(){
  agent.close(function(param1){
    agent.connect(connectCallback);
  });
}, 20 * 60 * 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Sometimes push notifications may not come.
2. The code is written for all occasions? (app close/ active / inactive / background)
3. The code is tested for same occasions?

Comment: Is there any reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and i resolved it by the following way:-

write this in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
        } else {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge];
        }
```

It will trigger a Permission alert to the user.
If he allows, then send the device token in success method :-

```
#pragma PushNotification delegation

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {

    NSString *device = [deviceToken description];
    device = [device stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    device = [device stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    NSLog(@"My deviceToken is: %@", device);

    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [prefs setObject:device forKey:@"deviceToken"];

     // Now send device token to server
}
```

Comment: Already I have used this method to registered and send the device token to the server. Am receiving the notification always except few times

Comment: Please refer my answer.